# nginx: connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream for Docker setup

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have 2 Java App running at ports 8084 and 8085
Url for the server - `http://127.0.0.1:8085/hello/adi`

NGINX Configuration ::

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf** -

```
 upstream my-app1 { 
    server 127.0.0.1:8085; 
} 

upstream my-app2 { 
    server 0.0.0.0:8084; 
}

server { 
  listen 80; 
  server_name  localhost; 
    location / { 
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html; 
        index  index.html index.htm; 
     } 

   location /hello { 
     proxy_pass http://my-app1/hello/adi; 
   } 
   location /helloin { 
     proxy_pass http://my-app2/helloin/helloin/adi; 
   } 
 }
```

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** -

```
user  nginx; 
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1; 

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn; 
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid; 


events { 
    worker_connections  1024; 
} 


http { 
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types; 
    default_type  application/octet-stream; 

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" ' 
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" ' 
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"'; 

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main; 

    sendfile        on; 
    #tcp_nopush     on;
```

I am seeing this error :

> [error] 7#7: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /hello HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8085/hello/adi", host: "0.0.0.0:8080"

Comment: Command i used to start nginx docker - `docker run -p 8080:80 -d nginxproxy1
`

Comment: Only the `my-app1` upstream is not working?

Comment: @dnlnrs yes, when i am trying to hit url from browser http://localhost:8080/hello, it throws above error!

Comment: @dnlnrs, when I hit http://127.0.0.1:8080/ it redirects to nginx, which is done correctly!

Comment: Have you tried to also use `0.0.0.0` for the `my-app1` upstream?

Comment: Yes, i tried it